# LLVM IR gen - find stack allocated variable by name

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have created an AllocaInst using new AllocaInst(...) within some block and have provided a name for it.

Having done this, is it possible for me to search for this stack variable by the name I gave for it (assume the AllocaInst* returned is not available anymore) ?

Answer (score 0):

`llvm::Value` has a `getName()` method you can query. So theoretically you can iterate over your function (or basic block, or whatever) looking for a value with some name.

But why would you really need to do this, though? It makes much more sense to not "lose" the `Instruction*` returned by `new AllocaInst`.